# Linking against boost libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, ldd

I'm having trouble building/running with some boost shared libraries.

Compilation works:

```
$ g++ -l boost_filesystem -l boost_program_option
$
```

But runtime fails:

```
$ ./a.out 
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_filesystem.so.1.80.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

As expected, `ldd` complains:

```
$ ldd a.out 
        ...
        libboost_filesystem.so.1.80.0 => not found
        libboost_program_options.so.1.80.0 => not found
        ...
```

But, adapting the recipe offered [here](https://serverfault.com/a/480011), `ldd` appears to include `/usr/local/lib`:

```
$ ldconfig -v |& grep "/usr/local/lib:"
/usr/local/lib: (from /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf:2)
```

And `/usr/local/lib/` contains the required libraries:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     29 Oct 26 16:45 /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so -> libboost_filesystem.so.1.80.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 191992 Oct 26 16:45 /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.80.0
```

So my question is, why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40567915/543913) that that `ldd` uses a system cache, and that this cache needs to be explicitly updated via:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Doing this resolved my issue.